# How to list if employee has recorded time each week

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot

I have this data base where I record time punches. It has the fields listed below.

```
emplid,end_date,day0,day1,day2,day3,day4,day5,day6
```

The end_date is the last day of the week for that week(every Sunday). So if someone recorded there time for 5 weeks they should have 5 rows each with a different end date. What I'm trying to do Is create a list of people that forgot to record there time for any of the weeks up until today. I want one row that shows a list of all the weeks so far. E.g

```
emplid,Week1,Week2,Week3,Week4,Week5.
12345 ,1    ,1    ,1    ,0    ,1
```

This is what I have.

```
SELECT COUNT(end_date) AS Week1, 
       COUNT(end_date) AS Week2 
FROM   `aca_time_record` 
WHERE  `emplid` = 025580 
HAVING week1 = '2013-10-05' 
       AND week2 = '2013-10-12'
```

Comment: You should **not** be storing days in a columnar fashion. Learn normalization.

Comment: I didn't create the database, I don't care about how the days are stored, and I don't care if the days are null. I only care that there is a row with each weeks date on it. Any idea?

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You need to count the number of un-punched days for each employee per each week and then transpose it to your final structure. Please see this answer for details - [MySQL pivot table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/mysql-pivot-table).